# How can obtain the last access by user list for each user on DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

i want to get the last date of each user through an user list.

For example:

I have a column of users and other column with the date (in format '20190626').
I need to get only the last date of each user.

In the following code show all users and each date more times.

EDDDIC is a name of user column
EDUUS6 is a date column
EDUARC is a table of users

```
SELECT EDUDI1, EDUUS6
FROM VTABDAT.EDUARC WHERE EDUUS6 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY EDUUS6 DESC
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
SELECT EDUDI1, MAX(EDUUS6)
FROM VTABDAT.EDUARC 
GROUP BY EDUDI1
ORDER BY MAX(EDUUS6) DESC;
```

Filtering out the `NULL` values is not necessary because `MAX()` ignores them.

Comment: Thanks!, its works!, i was trying with IS NOT NULL because exist many items with that field null, but the 'is not null' sentence throw error. When i remove is not null, the query works but appears some nulls because is only field that exists for this user, but is a detail :D